# Iframe chart from Google Sheet file does not working / blank, with error on console

Tags: google-sheets, iframe

I have published a chart from Google Sheet and embedded it into an iframe so it can be shown in public. The chart is shown without any problem in the Google Sheet.

However, the chart is not showing anything in the public page / empty container and there are a lot of issues in the browser console as you can see in this error console log :
https://prnt.sc/8O1X1pcgb3eT

I also had made the Google Sheet file to be able to access by public and the result still the same.

Here is an example of the embedded Iframe :

```
<iframe width="600" height="371" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSbGLsqyv6dC9WIT7BmX0CGhqucwmSzuNEwz2DyrV4lUesn00eWuNuWkdA7norLmWKtHeOUpZomVMgR/pubchart?oid=339810208&amp;format=interactive"></iframe>
```

The sheet also made to public :
[image]

Result in the browser console :
[image]

Error in the browser console log :

```
1408372654-RitzChartRenderingJ2cl_j2cl_core.js:1902 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at 1408372654-RitzChartRenderingJ2cl_j2cl_core.js:1902:910
    at 1408372654-RitzChartRenderingJ2cl_j2cl_core.js:2148:4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have replicated this part of your project. I have also had the same issues  at first and was able to fix it by making sure that I have shared the file with anyone with a link with a view access. Getting Google Sheets in Iframe is really straight forward and your project issue might be caused by another part of your code and the part that was affected visually is the Chart. Can you also share a screenshot of the empty container this way the community will have more information.

Comment: I have edited the question with more information. Thank you

Comment: Did you publish the Google Sheet to get the iframe? Also can you try to do some isolation test with your code so you can narrow down which part of your code you can share to give the community an insight of what your project is facing?

Comment: I have made some progress here on my part and isolated that the issue was your iframe src url. It seems that it is returning a blank canvas hence the blank iframe. I am wondering where does your URL came from and it seems that it was not how it was supposed to be when sharing a Google Sheet and might be because you are targetting an specific Object on the Google Sheet. I am just wondering how did you came up with it

Comment: Thank you for your comment so far. This is how I get the Iframe code and share it : 
https://prnt.sc/nqr0Wgc-oQuj

Comment: Do you think you can share your Google Sheet on your question as a minimum reproducible sample so I can try to pull it on my own. Then check if the same issue will persist?

Comment: Sure, here it is : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10mIlncdvElY_LvODQw9YdE6cMlRmAv57XvnzUbiOKbQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much for that file, I have clear information about this now. Upon checking here there is an actually bug going with Geo Chart not rendering which resurfaced back on August 2023. Here is the link with Community Expert discussion: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/141482118/geo-charts-are-blank-when-published?hl=en. This is the issue tracker link you can post here to up the issue and let Google Support know about your situation: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296337585

Comment: Thank you for your support and information. It is really appreciated.